# Serilog: azure webjob logging doesn't seem to work when hosted in azure?

Tags: azure, logging, serilog, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have azure webjob sdk (v3.0.3) app which has been configured to use serilog for logging.
The log seems to work when I run the app locally in my system. Below is the configuration:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var builder = new HostBuilder()
                        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(SetupConfiguration)
                        .ConfigureLogging(SetupLogging)
                        .ConfigureServices(SetupServices)
                        .ConfigureWebJobs(webJobConfiguration =>
                        {
                            webJobConfiguration.AddTimers();
                            webJobConfiguration.AddAzureStorageCoreServices(); //this is to store logs in azure storage 
                        })
                        .UseSerilog()
                    .Build();
                builder.Run();
            }
}
```

The code for SetupConfiguration is below:

```
  private static void SetupConfiguration(HostBuilderContext hostingContext, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
            _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
        }
```

The code for setting up services:

```
private static void SetupServices(HostBuilderContext hostingContext, IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(_configuration);
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(_configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
        _logger = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger("test");
    }
```

The logging is setup as following:

```
  private static void SetupLogging(HostBuilderContext hostingContext, ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
        {
            loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
            loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
            loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true);
        }
```

In my TimerTrigger method I'm using the logger:

```
[Singleton]
        public async static Task Trigger([TimerTrigger("%Job%")]TimerInfo myTimer)
        {           
          _logger.LogInformation($"From Trigger {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()}");

        }
```

In appSettings.json, serilog is configured as follows:

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "RollingFile",
            "Args": {
                "pathFormat": ".\\Log\\log-{Date}.txt",
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 7,
                "fileSizeLimitBytes": 5000000,
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {EventId} [{Level}] [{Properties}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

the folder "Log" and the log files get created when i run the app locally. But when I publish the webjob, the "Log" folder or the log file is not created in the "app_data" folder of webjob. Can anyone help me figureout how to configure serilog to make it work with webjobs?

Following are the nuget packages used:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `serilog` in `WebJob` , you need to install this package `Serilog.Extensions.WebJobs`. Then after configuring the `serilog`, you would be able to use it.

**You must inject the ILogger rather than using the global Log.Logger otherwise the log messages will not be written to the Microsoft Azure WebJobs dashboard.**

About the detailed description about how to configure and use `serilog`, you could refer to this [doc](https://github.com/JSkimming/serilog-extensions-webjobs).

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Note, this no longer works with WebJobs V3: https://github.com/JSkimming/serilog-extensions-webjobs/issues/11